# Is there a way to not have a username for Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to not have a username in Minecraft PE? I'm playing on an iPad mini.

Comment: Steve or Alex would be a neutral, unidentifiable name, but other than that, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to avoid having a username in Minecraft PE.